# Python: how can I get the smoother-starting-point in graph?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

What I want to get is the point, `(x, y)`, where the y value getting smoother for given x and y values.

For example,

```
x = range(10)
y = [0.3, 0.37, 0.41, 0.52, 0.64, 0.68, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I want to get the red-circle point (or near point) where the graph starts  getting stable.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: How do you define "smooth" or "stable"?

Comment: @chrisz the point where the y value stop to change a lot ! it doesn't have to be a exact point but close one.

Comment: Not to be antagonistic but define “a lot”, 25%...3%...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is *slope* or first order difference more exactly, to get an idea where the curve starts to smooth out, you can calculate the first order difference / slope and find out the first index where the slope is below a certain threshold:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(10))
y = np.array([0.3, 0.37, 0.41, 0.52, 0.64, 0.68, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74])

slopes = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)
idx = np.argmax(slopes < 0.02)  # find out the first index where slope is below a threshold

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.scatter(x[idx], y[idx], s=200, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome solution!